# Advising on what to do with 4 year old snapshot on HyperV

Tags: snapshot, hyper-v

I recently came across a server in a client that they have very old snapshots.
What should I do with these insanely old snapshot? Is there a risk of virtual disk corruption if I exclude all these snapshots?
Should I exclude one by one? Oldest to newest? Or exclude the whole snapshot tree at once?

[image: files]

[image: snaphosts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest export this particular VM to some backup location, then try to delete snapshot tree. In case something goes wrong restore VM from exported location.